# 3V ±0.1% reference

Tags: reference

I've been looking for a 3V ±0.1% reference in a SOT-23 package to replace my current ±0.5% solution of a TL431 and about 5 passive 0603 components.

At the moment I've found LM4040A30 which is $1 at 1ku, and comes in a SOT-23 package. It also requires a 0603 resistor, but is stable without a capacitor.

I'm wondering if anyone has any better solutions. Even more awesome would be something like an ultra stable precise zener diode in 0603 or 0805 size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the LM4040 is the way to go.  I don't know of any "pre-biased" shunt diodes, and if there were they would likely cost more and you would have to weigh that against the scant space savings.

If you can ease up on the 0.1% to 0.2 (B-grade) or 0.5 (C), the prices seem to drop quite dramatically.

Comment: I could probably go with 0.2%. Accuracy isn't crucial, but if I can have it for not much more ($1 vs. 60 cents being one example) I'd spec it in.